# How to preserve original code formatting of git repo?

Tags: git, sublimetext3, spaces

Whenever I **clone repo** in **local environment** the code formatting i.e. **spaces are converted to tabs** no matter what ever I do even after explicitly using the option to **"Convert Indentation to Spaces"** (I am using **sublime text3**) it **still converts** in to **tabs** at time of **commit** and it adds a lot of changes even if I add 2 lines of code. at time of commit I get.

[image]

basically it adds lot of changes. so is there way to deal with it?

Comment: git itself should not touch anything, are you sure it is not your editor or else tool? Does it happen if you use some simple text editor like `nano` or notepad, if you are at windows

Comment: @max630 yup I think it's sublime text 3 that's messing up the formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "-Xignore-space-change" option to prevent git convert whitespace.